# Loading Select options via ajax and then setting a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select field, `#parentCatSelect` whose values get generated via AJAX / PHP after the page loads via the function `acLoadParentCategories`.

The function needs to be used two separate ways, first to create a new part (which works fine) and secondly to update a part. When a user updates a part, all the form values (including this one) should be loaded from values in the Database via AJAX. All values load properly, except this one.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my value is not getting setting after the select values load.

My function to load the categories via ajax:

```
var acLoadParentCategories = function( callback ) {

    var _data = {
        action: 'ac_ajax_load_parent_cats'
    };

    jQuery.post(
        the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        _data,
        function( response ) {

            var results = JSON.parse(response.results);
            var html = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
                html += '<option value="' + results[i].cat_id + '">' + results[i].cat_name + '</option>';
            }

            jQuery('#parentCatSelect').append(html);
        }
    );

    callback();
    return;
};
```

and where I am to load it, and then properly set the val

```
acLoadParentCategories( function() {
    console.log('happening');
    jQuery('#parentCatSelect option[value="1"]').attr('selected', true);
});
```

The `console.log` statement gets called correctly, but no matter what I try, I cannot get the value to set properly after the select box gets generated. What am I doing wrong?

(For clarity, I know that I am manually assigning the value of "1" instead of dynamically loading the ID. I did this just to see if it would work, and still no dice.)

Comment: If you put `jQuery('#parentCatSelect option[value="1"]').attr('selected', true);` above `callback()` is it working correctly?

Comment: Sorry put the `callback();` after `jQuery('#parentCatSelect').append(html);`

Comment: because your callback will be called before the ajax completes.. let me know if it solves your issue..

Comment: yes, that solves the issue. How do I make the callback load after AJAX completes?

Comment: Because your `callback()` gets executed before your ajax completes.. your callback wll work on the same position if your ajax call is synchronous.. but its not good..

Comment: Let me add as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you have addd your `callback()` function after `$.post`  which is async by default.  So, your 'callback()' will execute before the ajax complete.  You got two options here

1. Make your `$.ajax` sync which I dont suggest.
2. Call your callback after `jQuery('#parentCatSelect').append(html);` (success block of `$.post`) i.e after your DOM is populated with values.

Hope it helps..